# How do you specify an option to Doxygen's \fileinfo command?

Tags: doxygen

> All commands in the documentation start with a backslash () or an at-sign (@). If you prefer you can replace all commands starting with a backslash below by their counterparts that start with an at-sign.
> <sub>https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html</sub>

> `\fileinfo['{'option'}']`
> Shows (part) of the file name in which this command is placed. The option can be name, extension, filename, directory or, full, with
>
> - name the name of the file without extension
> - extension the extension of the file
> - filename the filename i.e. name plus extension
> - directory the directory of the given file full the full path and filename of the given file.
>
> In case no option is specified the filename is used unless FULL_PATH_NAMES is set to YES in which case full is used.
> <sub>https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfileinfo</sub>

My Doxyfile:

```
PROJECT_NAME = hello-world
PROJECT_NUMBER = 0.1.0

INPUT = "C:/dev/hello-world/src" 
INPUT += "C:/dev/hello-world/doc/mainpage.txt"

OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = "C:/dev/hello-world/build/doc"

OUTPUT_LANGUAGE = English

FILE_PATTERNS = *.c *.h
RECURSIVE = YES
```

My attempted main page, `mainpage.txt`:

```
/**
  @mainpage Main page
  @page My test main page
  Generated from @fileinfo['{'directory'}']
*/

Here is some normal text.
```

The text from the resulting generated HTML page:

> Generated from C:/dev/hello-world/doc/mainpage.txt ['{'directory'}']

**What is the proper syntax to manipulate Doxygen's `\fileinfo` command with its advertised options?**
I want to be able to manipulate the generated HTML with the file's name, extension, filename, and directory.

I have tried the following variations on the `\fileinfo['{'option'}']` command:

- `@fileinfo['{'directory'}']` result: `Generated from C:/dev/hello-world/doc/mainpage.txt ['{'directory'}']`
- `@fileinfo['{directory}']` result: `Generated from C:/dev/hello-world/doc/mainpage.txt ['{directory}']`
- `@fileinfo[{directory}]` result: `Generated from C:/dev/hello-world/doc/mainpage.txt [{directory}]`
- `@fileinfo[directory]` result: `Generated from C:/dev/hello-world/doc/mainpage.txt [directory]`
- `@fileinfo[{'directory'}]` result: `Generated from C:/dev/hello-world/doc/mainpage.txt [{'directory'}]`
- `@fileinfodirectory` result: `Generated from @fileinfodirectory`

What is the magic combination of quotes, curly braces, and square brackets to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The magic combination of quotes, curly braces, and square brackets is:

1. No quotes at all.
2. No square brackets at all.
3. Curly braces around the enumerated option.

E.g.: `@fileinfo{directory}` result: `Generated from C:/dev/hello-world/doc`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35697793)

Comment: @Ouroborus: This is the author’s post and I believe it does offer an answer to their question. It would benefit from further explanation over the syntax to help future readers, but it’s not a follow up question or critique.

Comment: @StoneThrow What about the \example command, whose description from the documentation is `\example['{lineno}'] <file-name>`.  Does this become `\example1 file_name` or `\example{1} file_name` or `\example[1] file_name`?  I'm confused!

Comment: Never mind.  I was reading the command description completely wrong.  The proper syntax is `\example{lineno} file_name`.  `lineno` a command option, not a line number in the example file.  Still confused.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - you have it right, so I don't think there's any reason to be "still confused." :) You're correct: if you want to use the optional line number, an example would be `\example{lineno} example_file.cpp`, and the effect is the addition of line numbers in the generated documentation of `example_file.cpp`. In other words, you can think of the optional `{lineno}` as a formatting command for how Doxygen renders your file in the html: with or without line numbers in the left column. I hope that helps, but feel free to ask a new question if you need a deeper answer than what I can fit here

Comment: Indeed and thanks.  Unfortunately, the confusion stems from my not understanding how to include an example without the function's text descriptions moving from the function's page to the Example page.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/78228513/11722442.