# Doxygen Example Command Changing Function Comments

Tags: doxygen

### Context

Doxygen 1.10.0, Visual Studio Community 17.9.4, C++20 codebase.

I have been incrementally and successfully adding documentation code to the project.  Everything's been good so far up the learning curve.  I've just started introducing examples into the codebase and this is my first attempt.  I have the following function whose documentation output, pre-example insertion, is as expected:

```
/*! \brief A function to return the name as a string

The function retrieves the name string from a vector of names.  The index into the vector is the object's data member.
If the input parameter is not provided, the default is the name vector containing the standard names. 
\param [in] Strings is a vector containing name strings.
\return The current name as a string.
\exception out_of_range exception thrown if String's bounds are exceeded.  This indicates that either the vector doesn't have enough elements or the month number is out of range.
*/
std::string WxM::GetCurrentString(const std::vector<string>& Strings) const
{
// code removed for brevity
}
```

Without any example command, the documentation is correctly contained and properly formatted on the HTML output page under the Classes > Class List > WxM > GetStringName() page.

### What I've Done

1. I have added the path to the example files directory to Doxygen's INPUT > EXAMPLE_PATH field.
2. I have added the same path to the INPUT > EXCLUDE field.
3. I added the following lines after the \exception command line:

```
\example{lineno} GetCurrentString_Example.cpp
This is an example of how to use the GetCurrentString function.
```

4. I have created the GetCurrentString_Example.cpp file to the appropriate directory, containing

```
main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> Names = { "Test", "Test Again", ... };
    WxM WxMInstance;

    // current now contains the name.
    std::string current = WxMInstance.GetCurrentString(Names);
}
```

Doxygen reports no errors or warnings related to the example.

### Expected Output

I expected the example code to be displayed in the output HTML under its own heading on the function's documentation page, after the function's signature, \brief and main descriptions, and the \param, \return and \exception texts, and before the Definition location reference and caller graph.

### Actual Output

The function's page now contains only the function signature, an Examples header with a reference to the example, and the "Definition at.." location reference and caller graph.  The remaining text has disappeared.  However, all the text, including the sample code, appears when I follow the example link which takes me to the new main menu Example category.

How do I retain the previous style (the function description on its own page) and list the example code on that page?  Is this the default behaviour?

The Doxygen \example example is not particularly helpful or rich enough to provide insight.  I've Googled for any clues and submitted the question to a coding AIChat, but this is pretty specific question.  I've found little that addresses this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem you described, and I think I have a solution to your need: use the `\include` directive, instead of `\example`.

I've taken the liberty of adding a class around your code example, just to get a minimally compilable example:

```
// WxM.h

#include <string>
#include <vector>

/*! \brief The WxM class
 */
class WxM {
public:
  /*! \brief A function to return the name as a string
  The function retrieves the name string from a vector of names.  The index into the vector is the object's data member.
  If the input parameter is not provided, the default is the name vector containing the standard names.
  \param [in] Strings is a vector containing name strings.
  \return The current name as a string.
  \exception out_of_range exception thrown if String's bounds are exceeded.  This indicates that either the vector doesn't have enough elements or the month number is out of range.

  \b Example
  \include GetCurrentString_Example.cpp
  */
  std::string GetCurrentString(const std::vector<string>& Strings) const
  {
    return "Hello, world!";
  }
};
```

Note specifically `\include GetCurrentString_Example.cpp` instead of `\example GetCurrentString_Example.cpp`.

`\include <file>` has the effect of embedding your specified file "inline" within the "scope" of the current documentation, whereas `\example <file>` seems to have the effect of creating a link to your specified `<file>`.

You've already read the Doxygen documentation, obviously, but for future readers who stumble into this answer, the `\example` documentation is [here](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdexample), and the `\include` documentation is [here](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinclude).
Doxygen provides an example of how `\example` renders [here](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/example/html/examples.html), which is in line with our observation. So, far as I can tell, what we've observed is the default and only possible behavior from `\example`.

`\example` requires you to specify `EXAMPLE_PATH` in your Doxyfile, which you noted you've already done, so there should be nothing else you need to add/edit in your Doxyfile.

The explicit blank line after `\exception` appears necessary. Without it, the bolded word `Example` appears in the same paragraph as the `\exception` content.

(My conjecture: I suspect the explicit blank line is because of how Doxygen separates between different "categories" of commands.
Note that `\example`, `\include`, etc. are in a "--- Commands for displaying examples ---" section of the Doxygen documentation, while `\b` is in a "--- Commands for visual enhancements ---" section.
I might intuit that even with only a single carriage return between `\return` and `\exception`, it would be "clear" to Doxygen that the only reasonable behavior would be to separate those two commands' content into separate paragraphs, whereas perhaps a single carriage return between a command's content and more content (including a visual-enhancement command) is implicitly concatenated into the same paragraph. For example, the author might simply want to honor a right-margin as he's writing `\exception`'s content.)

The `\include` directive seems to honor the `{lineno}` option, so `\include{lineno} GetCurrentString_Example.cpp` will include the content of that file with line numbers on the left.

Last: as you noted in your comment, `\snippet['{'option'}'] <file-name>` is another viable option, with rendering differences vs. `\include` documented [here](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsnippet).

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.  It works and completely meets the need.

Your understanding is correct.  The comments are in a .cpp not a .h, and the function documentation somehow **moves** to the Example section of the Doxygen output.

I note that the blank line between \exception and \b is critical otherwise the example blends with the \exception text (or any other text) ahead of it.  The use of \include removes the output's root-level menu, Example.  Not a bad tradeoff.

\b is a nice touch.

Comment: \snippet['{'option'}'] <file-name> ( block_id ) also works well for this functionality and permits all examples, delineated with bounding block_id tags, to be in the same file and accessed through those tags.